# The moduli space of genus $0$ curves with $n$-punctures and complete linear systems on $\mathbb{P}_k^1$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, moduli-spaces

Let $\mathbb{P}_k^1$ be the projective line over an algebraically closed field $k$. The points of $(\Gamma(\mathbb{P}_k^1, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}_k^1}(n))-\{0\})/k^* = \mathbb{P}_k^n$ corresponds to the effective divisors of degree $n$ on $\mathbb{P}_k^1$.

On the other hand, I also know that $\mathcal{M}_{0,n} = ((\mathbb{P}_k^1)^{\oplus n}/\Delta)/\operatorname{PGL}_2(k)$ where $\Delta$ is the weak diagonal.

It seems there should be direct relationship between the complete linear system of degree $n$ divisors on $\mathbb{P}_k^1$, i.e $\mathbb{P}_k^n$, and this configuration space $((\mathbb{P}_k^1)^{\oplus n}/\Delta)$. Is this truly the case and, if so, how may one pass from this complete linear system to this configuration space?

Comment: $((\mathbb{P}_{k}^{1})^{\oplus n}\backslash\Delta)$ is the configuration space for $n$ labelled or numbered points on $\mathbb{P}_{k}^{1}$. On the other hand, $\mathbb{P}_{k}^{n}$ parametrizes collections of $n$ unordered collections of points on $\mathbb{P}_{k}^{1}$. So you can go from the first to the second by taking a quotient by the action of the symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}_n$.

Comment: Ok. So $\mathbb{P}_k^n$ is the space of unordered punctures on $\mathbb{P}_k^1$. Are you saying that the action of the symmetric group on $\mathbb{P}_k^n$ will result  in $(\mathbb{P}_k^1)^{\oplus n}$ ?

Comment: Also, how does the symmetric group act on $\mathbb{P}_k^n$? I think it would have to have a Lie Group (group scheme) structure in order to act on a scheme.

Comment: The symmetric group acts on $(\mathbb{P}^{1})^{\oplus n}$ by permuting the different copies of $\mathbb{P}^{1}$. Once you take the quotient, you get $\mathbb{P}^n$ on which the symmetric group does not act anymore (except by doing nothing).